# Plab 2 visa refusal twice

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, proof-of-ties, serial-refusals

The Decision

I have refused your application for a visit visa because I am not satisfied that you meet the requirements of paragraph(s) V 4.2-10 of Appendix V because:

I am aware that you were previously refused entry clearance. I have studied your previous application in addition to the information provided today. When assessing your application on the whole, I am not satisfied that you have met the requirements of the Immigration Rules on this occasion.

Although I note your sponsor states an intention to fund your trip I must also take into account the stated reason for your trip and your personal situation.

 You claim to be employed and propose to stay in the UK for 10 weeks whilst undertaking a PLAB Test. Although you have submitted a letter from your employer purporting to give you leave for 10 weeks no credible explanation has been provided as to why they would grant you 10 weeks leave of absence. Furthermore I note you have only worked for your employer since March 2019. Given the short period of your employment I am not satisfied that you would have accrued 10 weeks of holiday time. Furthermore you have not provided a satisfactory explanation why you would seek to spend 10 weeks in the UK in order to undertake a short test. Because of this, I am not satisfied that you are seeking entry just as a visitor for the length of time you say. Therefore I am not satisfied that you are genuinely seeking entry as a visitor for a period not exceeding 6 months or that you intend to leave the United Kingdom at the end of the period as stated by you. This also leads me to doubt the purpose of your application as stated.

 You state that you have worked as an ICU Medical Officer since March 2019 and that you have a current monthly income of 50000 NPR (£330) from all sources. You state you have personal savings of £2194 in support of your application. On the basis of the information and documents provided you appear to have no dependant relatives and little in the way of personal income or assets in your own country. In light of all the above I consider that you have failed to show sufficiently strong family, social or economic connections to your country of residence to satisfy me, on the balance of probabilities, that you intend to leave the United Kingdom on completion of a short visit.

For the reasons stated above I am not satisfied on a balance of probabilities that you are genuinely seeking entry as a general visitor for a limited period as stated by you, not exceeding 6 months; and I am not satisfied that you intend to leave the UK at the end of the period of visit as stated by you as

Please suggest me, for my next visa applications.

Comment: 10 weeks is exceedingly excessive for a 1-day exam, unless you are also taking some extensive courses in the UK in preparation - are you?  If so, did you detail these in your visa application?

Comment: What was the timeframe between your first refusal and your second application? Were the refusal reasons similar? How did you address the issues raised by the ECO in your first application? If you keep on submitting basically the same application, you’ll keep on getting refused.

Comment: I asked for 10 weeks visa because I was planning to join acedemy for the preparatory course of 2 weeks and 8 weeks of self preparation time . I did mistake , in asking for long period of time

Comment: My 1st visa refusal was due to following reason , there is gap of 4 months from my last visa refusal

Answer (score 2):

There are three straightforward reasons for your refusal.

1. You have asked for a ten week visa. Ten weeks in the UK is completely unnecessary to sit PLAB 2, and in view of your finances unreasonable.
2. You are intending to spend your entire savings, an entire year of income, on this trip. That also seems unreasonable. A ten week trip seems even more unreasonable given these finances. For a job to grant ten weeks vacation there would normally have to be special circumstances, which you have not indicated.
3. You seem to have no family ties that would keep you in your country, and a job that you have been in only  a short while. This is always a disadvatage.

Any future application should definitely only be for the minimum amount of time necessary to sit the exam. This will help with the plausibility of your job leave too. Beingbinbyour job longer and having more savings would not hurt. But the history of This application may hurt your future chances.

Comment: I'll suggest that a ten-week leave from work, where you've only worked a few months, left the ECO thinking that this wasn't an actual, real job. Offering such leave so early in your tenure is not something offered by employers, who are typically interested in having you on-site and working.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, with two refusals already, don't apply again any time soon. You will appear to be desperate and that will make your case weaker.

Secondly, you must address the issues raised by the ECO in your next application. Specifically, why do you need ten weeks for a short test; why should your employer release you for that time; how will you support yourself for the period of your visit (your claimed savings are nowhere near enough); what reasons do you have to return home after your visit.